# mmpeg changing the bitrate and file size of resulting file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using `ffmpeg` within a Python script (using `mmpeg-python`) in order to change metadata values but the bitrates and file size are also changed in the resulting video (bitrates are 'Velocidad de datos' and 'Velocidad de bits', sorry for non-english GUI):

[image]

The command I use is the following (removed the metadata part because the result is the same: the bitrate and the file size being changed):

```
import ffmpeg

ifile = 'borrar.mp4'
ofile = 'res.mp4'
ffmpeg.input(ifile).output(ofile).run()
```

How to preserve bitrates and so an aproximate file size.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, I had to add codec='copy':

```
.output(ofile, codec='copy')
```

This way the video file is not reencoded. Also the execution time is a lot more faster.